# Open a default View before any application launch

Tags: iphone, ipad

I am making security application in which I want to block some services of iPhone. So what I need is before any app launch, there is a simple view for users to enter password. If the password is correct, the app will launch otherwise app will close.

Comment: Are you asking about your own app or attempting to control what happens when other apps are launched?

Comment: When I will open any app which installed in my iphone I want that

Comment: are you asking that for a jailbroken iPhone?

Comment: what services do you want to block on the iPhone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do that if you want to publish your app through app store according to Apple's sandbox theory. Even there's a way to do it, you will get rejected from Apple.